# unfortunately camera has stopped working

Tags: android, video, camera

I am new  to android. I am capturing video using following code:

```
final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED = 1;
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
String ts = tsLong.toString();
String imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + galleryStart + "/" + FolderName + "/" + ts + ".mp4";

File file = new File(imagepath);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

If I haven't set  path its work fine other wise it gives me error." unfortunately camera has stopped working." I am setting path for saving the videos in particular directory.

Comment: did you add the permission in androidmanifest.xml file for write permission on external storage?

Comment: Yes I gave it. If I remove line intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri); it works fine. but I need to store it at particular directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Camera App Doesn't make you dir which you asked for in your `Uri`. So try to make it first.**

```
String imagepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + galleryStart + "/" + FolderName + "/" + ts + ".mp4";
File file = new File(imagepath);
  try 
  {
  if(file.exists() == false) 
    {
     file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     file.createNewFile();
    }
  } 
  catch (IOException e) 
  {
   Log.e(TAG, "Could not create file.", e);
  }
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Hope it helps you out!!

Comment: I already have directory and video is also gets stored in that. only the issue is it giving error.

Comment: @UttamKadam Try to use another extension in your video clip `instead of .mp4 try .3gp`